# Add a div and change the classes or navigation menu using wordpress walker?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, navigation

I want to know how to make a WordPress wp_nav_menu() or wp_list_pages() Walker class that will generate nav menu output like this?

```
<!-- Level1 -->
    <li class="current">
            <a href="#">Name</a>
<!--Level2-->
            <div class="nav-sub">
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
                            <li>
                                    <a href="#">Name</a>
<!--Level3-->
                                    <div class="nav-sub">
                                            <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                            <a href="#">Name</a>
<!--Can Add Unlimited levels If Possible-->
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Name</a>
                                            </li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
    </li>

    <!-- This is One Level only -->
    <li>
            <a href="#">Name</a>
    </li>
```

I tried many ways but can't just figure it out.
Here is the current output using wp_list_pages()

```
<ul class="myclass">
<li id="home"><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2 page_item_has_children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/sample-page/">Sample Page</a>
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/sample-page/home/">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/page-no-sub/">page no sub</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I have already read this article here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu But can't figure out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Edit :
>
> Well, look the differents parameters and call your menu

```
<?php
class Child_Wrap extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth)
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"div-sub\"><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth)
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul></div>\n";
    }
}

wp_nav_menu( 


    array( 
        'menu' => 'navigation',//(i created this menu on the backend of wordpress)
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'menu-sidebar', 
        'menu_class'      => 'menu-class',
        'menu_id'         => 'menu-id',
        'theme_location' => 'primary', 
        'walker' => new Child_Wrap() 

    ) 



 ); ?>
```

You can specified many parameters (id menu, class and id container etc...)

[source class walker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322193/how-can-i-add-a-div-around-wordpress-ul-container)

[Should you find your happiness here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

[Name menu screen ('menu' => 'navigation')](http://screencast.com/t/U8brdSBbtnaP)

Comment: I see, but do you know how to add <div class="nav-sub"> before the sub-level <ul> which can be seen in the first field of codes?

Comment: u need complete 2 parameter ($container & $container_class). I specified on my example. i will complete my example in 5 min.

Comment: This is what I get now using your code: http://pastebin.com/6whPQQP9 also please check if my PHP code is correct: http://pastebin.com/ryJTAvLm

Comment: I add Walker_nav_menu class and i correct my code (forget one ","), i understand what you do now ^^'

Comment: Now here is the code, looks even worse http://pastebin.com/NzQanhQV, is there any problems with my WP version? It's 3.7.1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41098/discussion-between-user2248259-and-coloo)

Comment: 'menu' => 'navigation' | put your real menu name navigation = My menu